# Extensions for Visual Studio 2022 Live Share

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2022, visual-studio-extensions

Is there any Live Share extensions for Visual Studio 2022 for Visual Studio Code to automatically update the webpage locally when saving the code?

I need to watch changings on website ( local host ) when writing code

Comment: I think the Hot Reload feature achieves what you are after.  Do you have that enabled? I think you may still need to refresh page though whenever you make a change.

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, I guess you want to use the Live Share function of vs2022 in visual studio code.

You can download [Live Share](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MS-vsliveshare.vsliveshare) extension, and you can refer to this document: [Install and sign in to Live Share in Visual Studio Code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/liveshare/use/install-live-share-visual-studio-code)